# "Access Denied" when accessing Samba share from Windows PC

Tags: permissions, samba

I configured Samba to share the root of a hard disk on my local network. I've done this once before and it worked fine. However, when I went to access the share I set up, Windows gives me an error message saying this:
*N: is not available.*
*Access is denied.*

I've never encountered this before, and could use some help :P

Comment: Need a wee bit more info. Edit your original question and add the answers to these questions: What version of Ubuntu are your using? What is the output of these two commands - without quotes: "testparm -s" "net usershare info --long"

Comment: Will do that tomorrow. I've shut the system down and put it away (it was right in front of my desk) so I'll pull it out tomorrow and test those commands.